# How to derive the hard thresholding estimator?

Tags: numerical-optimization, regularization

The minimization problem is
$$
\min_{\mu\in R^p} \sum_{i=1}^p (y_i-\mu_i)^2 + \lambda^2\sum_{i=1}^p \mathbb{1}(\mu_i\neq0)
$$
for $y\in R^p$. This is also known as $l_0$ regularization. The solution is given by 
$$
\hat{\mu_i}= y_i \mathbb{1}(|y_i|>\lambda).
$$
Does anybody know how to derive the solution or give some references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This $p$-dimensional problem decomposes into $p$ one-dimensional problems of minimizing $(y_i-\mu_i)^2+\lambda^2\mathbb 1(\mu_i\ne0)$. You can either choose $\mu_i=0$, or if you don't, the second term is constant and you might as well minimize the first term and choose $\mu_i=y_i$. The solution you give chooses the option of those two that minimizes the sum.